# Why did Dr. Pershing roll over so easy?

Tags: star-wars, the-mandalorian

In *The Mandalorian* chapter 16, "The Rescue", Dr. Pershing is

> captured by the rescue party.
>  He then proceeds to tell them where on the ship Grogu is held. He also informs them about the presence of the Dark Troopers.

He volunteers information that they did not have, nor were asking for. And if he hadn't informed them, the team wouldn't have stood a chance against the Dark Troopers.

Why did he do that? It amounts to betrayal.

Comment: He did the same thing in season 1.  He probably remembers if he just cooperates Mando won't hurt him.

Comment: Can't believe an Imperial would be so treacherous.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pershing seems to be a scientist-with-no-allegiance type - he works for the Empire because it gives him the resources and opportunities to research and sate his scientific curiosity.

He also seems to care (even a little bit) about The Child's wellbeing - or at least claims to in Season 1.

Also note that immediately before switching to help the Mandalorian and crew, he was held hostage at gunpoint by the very people who were supposed to be protecting him. That kind of experience causes one to reconsider options on who you should befriend. He's hoping that being helpful to the Mandalorian and his Republic Marshall friend will probably put him in good standing with the Republic now he's away from the Imperial Remnant.

Plus, he can always claim coercion if recaptured by Moff Gideon.

Answer (score 1):

Why assume that Dr. Pershing is brave?  He knows they just killed many imperial personnel.  He has no way of beating them.  Better to tell them what they want to know than to wait and be tortured/killed.

Comment: True, but he actually volunteers information they did not have nor were asking for. I've updated the question to reflect that.